# Horusec v2.8 is not working in CI Docker in Docker environment

Tags: docker, go, gitlab-ci

### The issue

The Horusec Docker image starting from version 2.8 is not working properly inside a DinD CI/CD like GitLab CI.

### Debugging

Using this line:

```bash
docker version -f '{{json .}}' | jq
```

I have this output inside the CI:

```json
{
  "Client": {
    "Platform": {
      "Name": ""
    },
    "Version": "23.0.1",
    "ApiVersion": "1.42",
    "DefaultAPIVersion": "1.42",
    "GitCommit": "a5ee5b1",
    "GoVersion": "go1.19.5",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Arch": "amd64",
    "BuildTime": "Thu Feb  9 19:45:43 2023",
    "Context": "default"
  },
  "Server": {
    "Platform": {
      "Name": "Docker Engine - Community"
    },
    "Components": [
      {
        "Name": "Engine",
        "Version": "23.0.1",
        "Details": {
          "ApiVersion": "1.42",
          "Arch": "amd64",
          "BuildTime": "Thu Feb  9 19:48:50 2023",
          "Experimental": "false",
          "GitCommit": "bc3805a",
          "GoVersion": "go1.19.5",
          "KernelVersion": "5.4.109+",
          "MinAPIVersion": "1.12",
          "Os": "linux"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "containerd",
        "Version": "v1.6.16",
        "Details": {
          "GitCommit": "31aa4358a36870b21a992d3ad2bef29e1d693bec"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "runc",
        "Version": "1.1.4",
        "Details": {
          "GitCommit": "v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "docker-init",
        "Version": "0.19.0",
        "Details": {
          "GitCommit": "de40ad0"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Version": "23.0.1",
    "ApiVersion": "1.42",
    "MinAPIVersion": "1.12",
    "GitCommit": "bc3805a",
    "GoVersion": "go1.19.5",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Arch": "amd64",
    "KernelVersion": "5.4.109+",
    "BuildTime": "2023-02-09T19:48:50.000000000+00:00"
  }
}
```

Using this command here:

```bash
docker run \
  -v "$(pwd):$CONTAINER_PATH" \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  horuszup/horusec-cli:XPTO horusec start \
  -p "$CONTAINER_PATH" -P "$(pwd)" --config-file-path "$CONTAINER_PATH/custom.json" -O "$fileName"
```

1. When `XPTO` is `v2.8` **(OUTPUT NOT EXPECTED)**:

```bash
Digest: sha256:829fce13916bfd1d61103be1e927d98f1ffbdfc4e78192b1fc1c1f8a4054e347
Status: Downloaded newer image for horuszup/horusec-cli:v2.8
time="2023-02-21T14:57:36Z" level=error msg="{HORUSEC_CLI} Your docker version is below of: " error=19.3
Error: docker not found. Please check and try again
Usage:
  horusec start [flags]
```

2. When `XPTO` is `v2.7`:

```bash
Digest: sha256:a2624618794abc503caac80dc213a35bfc51046bf80ff3248b4949808e83184c
Status: Downloaded newer image for horuszup/horusec-cli:v2.7
==================================================================================
time="2023-02-21T14:55:38Z" level=warning msg="{HORUSEC_CLI} No authorization token was found, your code it is not going to be sent to horusec. Please enter a token with the -a flag to configure and save your analysis"
time="2023-02-21T14:55:38Z" level=warning msg="{HORUSEC_CLI} XX VULNERABILITIES WERE FOUND IN YOUR CODE SENT TO HORUSEC, TO SEE MORE DETAILS USE THE LOG LEVEL AS DEBUG AND TRY AGAIN"
Error: analysis finished with blocking vulnerabilities
```

### My environment

- GitLab CI/CD

```bash
Running with gitlab-runner 15.9.0~beta.115.g598a7c91 (598a7c91)
  on blue-1.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default j1aLDqxS, system ID: s_b437a71a38f9
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
Using Docker executor with image docker:23.0 ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:cd27a71ea4555b
```

- Docker in Docker
- Horusec official Docker image

**Note:** this is working perfectly in my environment:

```
OS: Kali Linux (on the Windows Subsystem for Linux)
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.79.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

### References

1. Latest Horusec image [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/horuszup/horusec-cli/sha256-829fce13916bfd1d61103be1e927d98f1ffbdfc4e78192b1fc1c1f8a4054e347.sig/images/sha256-1b37f166a5249f18fded9c905ea0127c6d14d26ca6881bb6d2e90a447ca546d6?context=explore).
2. The [piece of code](https://github.com/ZupIT/horusec/blob/v2.8.0/internal/controllers/requirements/docker/docker.go#L39-L67) where I think the issue is.
3. The [Docker client](https://github.com/ZupIT/horusec/blob/v2.8.0/internal/services/docker/client/docker_config.go#L25) used by Horusec code.
4. A similar issue happened [here](https://github.com/ZupIT/horusec/issues/106).